# SimpleDateFormat parser quirky?

Tags: java

I would expect the following to fail with ParseException, yet it succeeds:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("201602-12")
```

This actually returns Tue Jan 19 00:00:00 CET 2016, as if it took the 20160201 date and subtracted 12 days from it :-D I have read the SimpleDateFormat javadoc regarding this, yet there is nothing related to this "subtracting" functionality. I would like to ask you guys more experienced with the weird ways of SimpleDateFormat - is this behavior correct? Is this behavior according to some spec I missed? Or is this a bug which needs to be reported to Oracle? This is on Java 1.8.0_72

Comment: Read up on "lenient".

Comment: Sorry, you're right - my bad. In my defense, it's not easy to connect this weird behavior to lenient - I thought that lenient will only fix you February 30th, and not formatting issues. I stand corrected.